# Put three string variable in one array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I would like to put three String variable in one array besides each other in C++. How can I do that most efficiently with as little code as possible? In fact, it must be a conversion of string class to CString type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried? just keep on adding your variable into arrays..

Comment: I wrote that with <for loop>, but I want sth much more efficiently if it is possible.

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: That's C++ language.

Comment: "I wrote that with <for loop>"  Show us your for loop, so that we can understand better what you want to do

Comment: When you say _String_ and _CString_ do you mean `std::string` and `char*` respectively? If not, are you using some proprietary classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it using the following code:

```
string str1 = "testing";
string str2 = " string";
string str3 = " concatenation";
string output = str1 + str2 + str3;
cout << output;
```

output will be:

`testing string concatenation`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] strArray = new String[give size of array];
strArray[0] = "str1";
strArray[1] = "str2";
strArray[2] = "str3";
```

Comment: It needs two elements to reach the characters of the string: strArray [i][j] but I want an array by only one element I can reach to the characters, it may be C-string.